# How do i compare year on change in a SQL database without hardcoding the years?

Tags: sql

I have a database with schema such as:

```
----------------------------------------------
SalesID | ProductID | ProductName | SalesDate
----------------------------------------------
 1      |  1        | Football   | 2020-01-07
 2      |  1        | Football   | 2019-01-08
 3      |  1        | Football   | 2019-01-08
 4      |  1        | Football   | 2019-01-08
 5      |  2        | Racket     | 2020-01-07
 6      |  2        | Racket     | 2018-01-07
 7      |  2        | Racket     | 2018-01-07
----------------------------------------------
```

What i want to do is to dynamically retrieve the total year on year change in the amount of sales for each year and its previous year. But in the case where there was no sales for a certain product in one year, then compare it to the next available one.

For example, the "Football" product had 3 sales in 2019 and 1 sale in 2020. So that is a decrease of 66%. And i want to print that.
The "Racket" product had 1 sale in 2020, none in 2019 but 2 in 2018. So i want to print it such that it had a decrease of 50%.

I would like to do this without hardcoding the years using a CASE WHEN statement.

My attempt can get the data i want for each year but if there is year that has no data it compares it anyway to it, instead of comparing it to the next year that contains sales data

```
declare @maxYear int
declare @minYear int
declare @saleChange int

set @maxYear = (select max(year(SalesDate)) from Products)
set @minYear = (select min(year(SalesDate)) from Products)

create table #temp(
 ProductName varchar(255),
 CurrentYear int,
 CurrentSalesCount int,
 PrevYear int,
 PrevYrSalesCount int,
 Growth int)

WHILE (@maxYear >= @minYear)
BEGIN
 insert into #temp
 select
  d.ProductName,
  CurrentYear = @maxYear,
  CurrentSalesCount = sum(case when year(d.SalesDate) = @maxYear then 1 else null 
end),
 PrevYear = @maxYear - 1,
 PrevYrSalesCount = sum(case when year(d.SalesDate) = @maxYear - 1 then 1 else null 
end),
 Growth = (sum(case when year(d.SalesDate) = @maxYear then 1 else null end) 
    -sum(case when year(d.SalesDate) = @maxYear - 1 then 1 else null end)) 

from Products d
group by
d.ProductName

 Set @maxYear = @maxYear - 1
 END

 select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query, tested at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=49149983b7ebc6c75606549b149391df)

```
SELECT 
pid as ProductId, 
salyr as SaleYear, 
cnt as SaleCount, 
LAG(cnt, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY salyr) AS PrevYearSale,
cnt - LAG(cnt, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY salyr) AS DiffPrevYear,
case when LAG(cnt, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY salyr) = 0 then 0
else 
round((cnt - LAG(cnt, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY salyr))*100
/(LAG(cnt, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY salyr)),2) end as PerDifference
FROM 
(Select productid as pid, 
extract(year from salesdate) as salyr, 
count(1) as cnt
from test
group by productid, extract(year from salesdate)
order by 1, 2)
;
```

Comment: Could you explain what the above SQL code does? Im not used to LAG functions. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest play with the dbfiddle, starting with the innermost query. Coming to LAG function, it was required because I had to operate on the previous record to get the percentage of sales change.

Comment: Updated my query for readability; do note the values generated for SaleCount, PrevYearSale, DiffPrevYear in dbfiddle. That will help you understand how LAG function works

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and window functions:

```
select year(salesdate), product, count(*) as cnt
       lag(count(*)) over (partition by product order by year(salesdate)) as prev_cnt,
       (count(*) * 1.0 /
        lag(count(*)) over (partition by product order by year(salesdate))
       ) as ratio
from t
group by year(salesdate);
```